# VB.Net inverse of a function to convert SAP Datetime to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, business-objects

I've this simple function in VB.net

```
Private Function SBODateTime2DateTime2(SboTicks As Long) As DateTime
    Dim str As String = Convert.ToString(SboTicks, 2)
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 8)
    If str.Length = &H38 Then
        str = str.Substring(1, &H37)
    End If
    Dim num As Long = Convert.ToInt64(str, 2)
    Dim time As New DateTime(&H7B2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Return time.AddMilliseconds(CDbl(num) / 1000.0)
End Function
```

That takes a SAP tick number like **444447614733000184** and it returns the Datetime, in this example is **06/01/2025 00:31:35**

The problem is that I don't know how to do the inverse of this procedure in VB.net mostly because there isn't a lot of documentation about SAP DateTime around.

Does anybody knows if it's possible to do the Datetime to SAP Datetime conversion?